# NGINX domain rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

What I am trying to achieve using nginx is this:

```
http://domain.com - redirects to http://otherdomain/page.html
http://www.domain.com - redirects to http://otherdomain/page.html
http://domain.com/* - redirects to http://otherdomain/*
```

Basically only the domain and the www should be redirected to an url link. Everything else should be redirected to another domain, but keeping the url like this:

```
http://domain.com/subdomain/page.html -> http://otherdomain/subdomain/page.html
```

If you have questions please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use $request_uri

see in http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html

Probably like below

```
server{
   location = /
   {
       rewrite ^ http://otherdomain/page.html;
   }
   location /subdomain
   {
       rewrite ^ http://otherdomain/$request_uri;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. That might work but actually i need something else and I think I was not able to explain it clearly. So it's like this:
    http://domain.com/asadasdsad -> http://otherdomain/asadasdsad
    http://domain.com/* -> http://otherdomain/*

Except for the domain.com and www.domain.com, I need a full url rewrite based on the initial request. If the user requests page.html, it will redirect to 2nd domain page.html. if the user requests subdomain/page.html it will redirect to the other domain subdomain/page.html.

Hopefully you understand what I am looking for.